# date function not working proprly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

in my `asp` web page i am using `ajax` calender to select date . i don't to user to select the past date or current date or more than 20 days from current date .

```
var today = new Date();
            var twentyDays = new Date();
            twentyDays.setDate(today.getDate() + 20);

            if (selectedDate.getDateOnly() <= todayDate.getDateOnly())
            {
                alert('Date Cannot be in the past or current date');
                sender._textbox.set_Value(null);
            }
            else if (selectedDate.getDateOnly() > twentyDays.getDateOnly())
            {
                alert('this is more than 20 days');
                sender._textbox.set_Value(null);
                return;
            }
```

but it not comparing the date .. 
this is my asp code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgCalender" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png" ToolTip="Select a Date" />
 <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calShow"  runat="server" PopupButtonID="imgCalender" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" TargetControlID="txtDate" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="CheckForPastDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: A javascript date object has no `.getDateOnly()` method ?

Comment: what should i do ?
but it is showing in option when i right clinking on code in visual studio. and also it working fine when i didn't added this line 
var twentyDays = new Date();
 twentyDays.setDate(today.getDate() + 20);

Comment: If your ASP calender thingy has such a method, great, but the date object doesn't, you have to use `twentyDays.getDate()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using server-side logic to handle this instead of JavaScript, as `today.getDate() + 20` will not work when the date will result in a date that is not in the same year as today (i.e. December 30th of the year).

Instead use the .NET Framework's `DateTime` object to add days and do comparison via ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods, like this:

Code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string CompareDate(string theDateToCompare)
{
    DateTime dateValue;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue))
    { 
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime twentyDaysFromNow = today.AddDays(20);

        if(dateValue <= today)
        {
            return "Date cannot be in the past or current date"; 
        }
        else if (dateValue > twentyDaysFromNow)
        {
            return "Date cannot be more than 20 days in the future";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "Unable to parse " + dateString; 
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add selector event here to trigger call to server side
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PageName.aspx/CompareDate",
        data: "{'CompareDate':'11/30/2013'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
                // The .d is part of the result so reference it
                //  to get to the actual JSON data of interest
                alert(result.d);
            }
            else {
                // No .d; so just use result
                alert(result);
            }
       }
    });
});
```

---

> Note: You will need to change the name of `PageName.aspx` to the name of your .aspx page. Also, the `.d` syntax was an anti-XSS protection put in by Microsoft in the ASP.NET 3.5 release of ASP.NET AJAX; therefore the check to see if the `.d` property is there or not.

Comment: but how can i get the selected date .i don't know to retrieve the selected date in ajax calender control. can you please explain me

Comment: think you'll find date object handles changes of year just fine

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of `getDateOnly()` which to my knowledge is not part of javascript Date object and use `getTime()`

Comment: `getDate` only returns day of month...that's not valid test